# Expected Literal constant error. How can I make a Private Const variable store non literal string

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

What are some methods to put together a non Literal string into a private const variable. According to the error produced from the code below.

Error: Expected literal constant

Code: 800A0415

```
Dim objExcel
Dim objWorkbook

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
    ("somepath\" & FILE.Name)

private const strSQL1 = "SELECT * FROM [" & objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & "$]"
```

Passed to the following code to open connection to ms access database:

```
EXCELRECORDSET.Open strSQL1, adoJET
```

I believe it needs to be a private constant since using a variant variable of subtype String causes other errors with ms access but, no issues when I use the following literal

```
private const strSQL1 = "Select * FROM [SomeHardCodedExcelSheetName$]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot by definition. You should simply be able to use

```
Dim strSQL1
strSQL1="SELECT * FROM [" & objWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name & "$]"
```

If that is causing you errors, let me know and we can take a look at those.

Comment: I get Error: Expected end of statement 
at line where I declare:
Dim strSQL1 as String

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice you were using VBScript, not VB/VBA. I have updated answer to reflect that VBScript only has one variable type; Variant.

Comment: I now receive the following Error: Multiple-step operation generated errors. Check each status
Line:238
Char: 9
Code: 80040E21

I do not believe the error is concerning this line since I do not get any issues when I hard code the sheet name into a private constant variable.
.Fields("ArrDate2").Value = EXCELRECORDSET.fields(26).Value

Comment: I assume you're using that within a `WITH`. That error is likely caused by either an invalid field name, or inserting too much data into the field. Try `msgbox`ing that field to verify correct name and connectivity. Also try inserting a single digit/character (depending on the field type) to ensure you're not inserting too much data.